# Java GWT VerticalPanel replace widget

Tags: java, gwt, replace, widget

Is it possible to replace an existing widget in an `VerticalPanel` in java GWT with another widget? I tried to do the following:

```
verticalPanel.remove(widget1);
verticalPanel.add(widget2);
```

This unfortunately adds the `widget2` at the end of the `verticalPanel` but I would like to replace the `widget1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `VerticalPanel.remove(int index)` and `VerticalPanel.insert(Widget w, int beforeIndex)`.

Comment: How do I find out the index of a specific widget? The position of the widget I would like to replace is not fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can always

```
verticalPanel.clear();
verticalPanel.add( widget2 );
```

Does the `.remove(...)` call return `true` or `false` - the latter would indicate that the widget is not present in the panel?

You may also try to [`.remove( int index )`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ComplexPanel.html#remove%28int%29).

Cheers,

Comment: The vertical Panel has more than just 2 Elements, it contains about 5 elements and I would like to replace the 3rd one...

Comment: the return is true so the widget is removed